# Changing ruby controller variable based on input from a view

Tags: ruby, button, view, haml, stripe-payments

I am using stripe to collect money for a website I am making.

Here is my view:

```
%script.stripe-button{"data-amount" => "10000", "data-description" => "A Generous Donation", "data-key" => Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key], src: "https://checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js"}
%br
%b Amount:
%br
%input
%script.stripe-button{"data-amount" => "", "data-description" => "A Generous Donation", "data-key" => Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key], src: "https://checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js",  style:"padding-left: 30px;"}
```

Here is my controller:

```
def create
    # Amount in cents
    @amount = 500

    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      :email => 'example@stripe.com',
      :card  => params[:stripeToken]
    )

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :customer    => customer.id,
      :amount      => @amount,
      :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
      :currency    => 'usd'
    )

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to charges_path
  end
```

For my first button, I am trying to send the data-amount to the amount variable. For the second, I am trying to collect a value from the input box and set the @amount variable and the data-amount tag in the stripe-button to collect the payment. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, this should have nothing to do with controller.

It looks all you need is to set the amount of the second button, once you have a valid input of number in the input.

This can be done by jQuery easily. Demo code:

```
$('#that_input').on('focusout', function(){
  if typoeof($(this).val()） == 'number'
    $('#second_button').data('amount', $(this).val())
});
```

What this block of code does is to assign the value of input to the second button's data-ammount attribute when inputting finished and focused out, if that input is a valid number.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done easily with a little of JS. Just handle the click event on each button, when handling the click, set the value value with either the `data-amount` in the first case, or get the `input` value in the second case. Then

- If using a form, set the value of the input with the appropriate name and submit it.
- If you are using AJAX, just post this in JSON or whatever you like.

[Edit]

After posting the variable to your controller, just get it from wherever you posted it, so if you used a form with

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" />
```

for your data, just use

```
@amount = params[:amount]
```

in your controller to get the value.

[/Edit]

Comment: Can I see an example of setting the @amount variable.

Comment: How can I set that to the hash for data-amount? When I try it rejects the value.